# Magento2 - hide special price products

Tags: product-collection

I would like to hide any products with a 'special price' from the main catalogue to only show them on a custom 'sale' page.

I could probably do this in M1 but I do not know what the general approach to this should be in M2.

I still want the special price products to show in the sale page and in upsells/cross sells.

Ideally I also have filtering on the sale page, the standard M2 widget does not allow for this but I think I can build a custom collection for this. Hence I am interested in a general approach rather than a fully working solution, just to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You mean hide product based on special price in produtct List page(category page)?

Comment: @aravind Yes, so they don't show in the normal category pages if special_price is set.